# There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I have two tables:

Table1

---

> c_ID float - PK
>   Field1
>   Field2
>   Field3
>   p_ID [uniqueidentifier]

and

Table2

---

> p_ID nvarchar
>   s_ID float

where both p_ID and s_ID are part of the primary key.

I tried to create a foreign key on Table1:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Table1_Table2 FOREIGN KEY (p_ID) 
    REFERENCES Table2(p_ID)
```

and I got an error:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table
>   'dbo.Table2' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key
>   'FK_Table1_Table2'.

Am I getting this error because data type of `p_ID` is uniqueidentifier and in Table2 `p_ID` is nvarchar? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Sheesh I hope those aren't your real column names...they are awful. The error is because Table2 has a composite key and your trying to establish a foreign key to a portion of the key. Also, why in the world do you have one table with a guid and then it is stored as varchar in another table? This means there will be an implicit conversion everytime you do an update. If the value is a guid you should always store it like that.

Comment: of course they are not real column names! Also I did not create the tables, so I have no control over the data types. Any word on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Like I said the problem is that you are trying to create a foreign key to only a portion of a composite key. You can' t do that. There must be something in place that signifies that column is unique, either the primary key OR a unique constraint. My guess is that p_ID in Table2 is not unique, hence the composite key.

Comment: True. p_ID in Table2 is not unique. It is only unique in combination with s_ID

Comment: Right that is what I am saying. You can't use that as a foreign key because it is only a portion of the primary key for that table.

Comment: To answer the question of whether there is a workaround, we would have to know what your goal is.   Right now there isn't actually a problem.   SQL Server is preventing you from creating an invalid relationship, and that's a good thing.   If there are duplicate values in Table2.p_ID, then how would you know which row you are referencing from Table1.p_ID?   What logic are you trying to create?

Comment: Not only must the foreign key reference all the columns of the related table key (primary key, unique constraint, or unique index), the column data types must be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to use a FK that includes the same columns that are in the PK

```
create table ParentTest (
SomeNumber int,
Name varchar(25),
PRIMARY KEY (SomeNumber, Name)
)


create table ChildTest (
SomeValue varchar(25),
SomeNumber int,
Name varchar(25),
FOREIGN KEY (SomeNumber, Name) references ParentTest (SomeNumber, Name)
)
```